# Hadoop Hello world on windows machine

Tags: php, mysql, windows, hadoop

I am not very familiar with hadoop. So I want to play around with it to understand it better.  Can I install hadoop on windows XP and do a Hello World in stand alone mode?

Note, my ultimate goal is to see if I can use it for an application I am developing. (The application will need to analyze lot of graph like data. I have the application POC written in PHP and using MySQL.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better to start from [Hadoop Quick Start documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/quickstart.html#Installing+Software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Hadoop initial study** :

Here, you can go through the MapReduce programs

[Hadoop MapReduce programs](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/)

**For your POC**

**a. PHP part**

We can write map-reduce programs in PHP

[MapReduce programs written in PHP](http://www.lunchpauze.com/2007/10/writing-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-php.html)

**b. MySQL part**

Use sqoop for import/export of tables from MySQL to HDFS ( Hadoop File system) and vice versa

[Sqoop User Guide](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Comment: source is outdated. Apparently the blog is only available to invited users.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to install Hadoop is using Cloudera.
Cloudera is not available for Windows, but you can download an Virtualbox or VMWare image and try it in a Virtual Box.

http://www.cloudera.com